# Using powershell to execute cmd commands

Tags: powershell

I love Linux's terminal. I found a package manager for windows called "Chocolatey" and thought if I combined that and powershell I might just have an alternative to the Linux terminal for windows. However, after installing packages I've found that I can't run them from Power Shell. I can get some of them to work using: & "mycommand"

There are a lot of obvious advantages to using Power Shell over CMD. Little things like "ls" instead of "dir" for example. I would really like to just be able to run cmd commands from power shell and hopefully without extra characters. Is there anyway to do this cleanly?

Comment: What commands are you trying to run?  You can launch executables from powershell the same way you would in cmd.  The only thing you don't get is cmd built-ins like FOR and CALL (for which Powershell has much more powerful alternatives), or batch processing.  For batch, you can just spawn a cmd process to execute your file.

Comment: FYI `ls` (and `dir`) in PowerShell are just aliases to `Get-ChildItem`, and you can easily define aliases in Command Prompt to make `ls` point to `dir` there as well. The existence of an alias to a command name you like from bash is **not** an "obvious advantage" to PowerShell (although it is the superior environment, this is **not** a reason for its superiority).

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell, dir and ls are just aliases to the cmdlet Get-ChildItem
You can add alias with the cmdlet : new-Alias

For example, if you want to add an "grep" alias from the cmdlet Select-String you can run :

```
New-Alias -name grep -Value Select-String
```

Powershell can run external executable, even without the &, as long as the executable is located in your PATH environment variable.

Are your external commands located in your PATH ?

To check that, run :

```
$env:PATH
```

If not, you can add a path to your PATH environment variable, like so :

```
$ENV:PATH += ";C:\Path\To\YourPackages\"
```

Comment: One common mistake is to try and alias commands like you would in bash. `alias foo='ls -laF'` for example. This does not work in powershell. However, you can instead use `function foo { ls -laF (at)args }` or something similar to achieve the same effect. I can't seem to figure out how to type a literal at sign without SO trying to reference a user.